# Gradually set transparency of nav drawer as it opens

Tags: android, transparency, opacity, transparent, navigation-drawer

I want to set the navigation drawer completely transparent and as the user slides open the nav drawer it gradually (following the users finger) becomes opaque. How can I achieve this?

Here is the XML layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RLayout02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#EDEDED" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#EDEDED"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:scrollY="0dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/welcomeHeader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_card_blue"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/welcomeHeader"
                android:textColor="#07BDEC"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/swipeOver"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/welcomeInfo"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_card_red"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:onClick="move"
                android:text="@string/swipe"
                android:textColor="#EC135A"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/welcomeInfo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/swipeOver"
                android:layout_below="@+id/welcomeHeader"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/my_button"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="2sp"
                android:text="@string/welcomeInfo"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgMin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="70dp"
        android:paddingRight="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/mp_black"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</FrameLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#DDDDDD"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp" />
```

Comment: Show me the script where you've build the drawer you have already.. I don't know what you have right now

Answer (score 0):

You probably have implemented the `DrawerLayout.DrawerListener` (you should for using the `onDrawerOpened` and `onDrawerClosed`) I'm not sure but you could try the `onDrawerSlide` which is called when you're sliding the Drawer. 
Thereby a parameter "offset" is given. I believe this is the new offset(distance of your slide movement) 
This gives a value between 0 and 1. 
In this method you could try to change the alpha of your drawer.

Try this:

```
 ActionbarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
@Override
onDrawerOpened(){};
@Override
onDrawerClosed(){};
```

**EDIT:**

```
@Override
onDrawerSlide(View drawerview, float slideoffset){
drawerview.setAlpha((1/255)*slideoffset);
}
```

try to set the alpha for the drawerview. It shouldn't set the alpha for the child views too.

This is just a quick draft so i'm not sure if it perfectly works(especially for the alpha formula) but you should look in this direction just try a bit with this.

**SHADOW EDIT:**

```
@Override
onDrawerSlide(View drawerview, float slideoffset){
drawerview.setAlpha((1/255)*slideoffset);
shadowDrawable.setAlpha((1/255)*slideoffset);
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(shadowDrawable);

}
```

Comment: I have worked out a possible solution but DrawerLayout.onInterceptTouchEvent is giving me a crash, any idea of how to override it or at least prevent it from being called? I made the DrawerLayout a childview instead of the parent which is why it is crashing.

Comment: You probably should keep it as a parent because the content of the drawer item you select will be placed inside a frame created by the drawer so the DrawerLayout.onInterceptTouchEvent can intercept the touch to check whether it's a touch for the drawer or the child view.. Then probably the crash will be gone.. But why do you have the DrawerLayout as a childview?

Comment: I just made it as a child view because if I want to set the transparency of the DrawerLayout it also sets the transparency of all its child views. My simple (also not the smartest) solution was to make it a child view.  Any ideas of a better way to get around this?

Comment: Put it back as a parent view and set the transparency for the background. Not for the whole view. maybe this is a solution.. Or else could you edit your post and add some script to it?\

Comment: I have updated my question with the XML layout (With the DrawerLayout as the parent)

Comment: I think you should set the transparency for the background. Have you tried my answer above?

Comment: Do you mean the drawers background? I wouldn't want to do that because the text wouldn't have the transparency effect.

Comment: Ow you want the whole drawer incl. the text to get the transition.. Check my edit.

Comment: So i have just used your edit (which sets the transparency of the text only) as well as your previous post (which sets the transparency of the background) and have achieved exactly what i wanted, but with one exception. I have not set the transparency of the drawer shadow so while the entire drawer is transparent, the shadow is still opaque. Any way around this other than removing the shadow?

Comment: I'll add that to my answer.. It should work if you've set your shadow with setDrawableShadow.. I don't know how memory/processor intesive it is. The idea behind it is to draw the shadow again during the slide. Check my answer

Comment: This is what i have used to create the shadow: mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);